# prevent item losing focus when refreshing list view in c#

Tags: c#, listview, focus

I have list view and some columns "ID", "product name" and "Vendor". I can add, edit or delete those items and after "messing up" with items list view is refreshed something like this.

```
listView.Items.Clear();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(item.ID.ToString());
    lv.SubItems.Add(item.Name.ToString());
    lv.SubItems.Add(item.Vendor.ToString());
    listView.Items.Add(lv);
}
```

so this method works fine except every time i refresh list focus of item is lost, which is logical because i deleted all items from list and filled it again. 
So my problem is how can i keep focus on edited and newly added items, primary when i edit some items i would like listview not to scroll to the top but to stay on place where that edited item was. 
I tried with method FindItemWithText and than setting focused items of listview to item that is found but it didn't work. 
Is there ant solution to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 5):

Save focused item's index to the variable:

```
int oldFocusedIndex = listView.SelectedItems[0].Index;
```

Later then you can restore focus executing:

```
listView.Items[oldFocusedIndex].Selected = true;
```

You can also make the item visible to the user due to the `ListView`'s scroll bar will remain at the top after the `Clear()` method:

```
listView.Items[oldFocusedIndex].EnsureVisible();
```

Comment: But i don't have a method .SelectedIndex? I can't get index with this.